# Http responce error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: java, android

In my android app I need to connect server and call some function 
this is what i am doing:

```
HttpConnector.httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = HttpConnector.httpclient.execute(HttpConnector.httppost);
```

where `nameValues` is the list of parameters (it is ok).
And I am getting the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

So what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in an Activity. You must do it in another Thread. Try using AsyncTask or new thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
               // HTTP stuff
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```